# How to open calendar with event - NSURL calshow:

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsurl, eventkit

I'm wondering if there is someone who knows how to launch calendar with a specific event from APP

I've done some research and I've come up with two ways to open  native  calendar from inside the app using NSURL

1. `"calshow://"` which opens calendar at current date
2. `"calshow:\(someNSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)"` which opens calendar with date of `someNSDate`

I also found [this website](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/NSURL) that lists `calshow:x?eventid=id` as url but I'm not sure if this works (listed as not public) and I couldn't get it working myself, tried using :

```
event.calendarItemExternalIdentifier
event.eventIdentifier
event.calendarItemIdentifier
```

currently I'm using this code to open the calendar app at the finalInterval date, date of the event

```
        if let day = hackathon?.start {

            let today = NSDate()
            let timeSince = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() // this plus
            let todayToFutureDate = day.timeIntervalSinceDate(today)
            let finalInterval = todayToFutureDate + timeSince

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "calshow:\(finalInterval)")!)
        }
```

What I'd like to do is to open up the calendar with an event id or something like that that would show the event

if you have any questions for more info just ask, I'll be around

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with this, create this function

```
func gotoAppleCalendar(date: NSDate) {
  let interval = date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
  let url = NSURL(string: "calshow:\(interval)")!
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Call the function using the event start date as parameter

```
 gotoAppleCalendar(event.startDate)
```

This open the apple calendar showing the added event

Comment: @duhseekoh This function IS NOT for add an event to the calendar, is for open and event previously added

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4 variant+**

```
func gotoAppleCalendar(date: Date) {
     let interval = date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
     let url = URL(string: "calshow:\(interval)")!
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure that's what I'm trying to clarify... you said you'll see an "added event"... as if you added the event with the code you wrote, but you did not do that.

Which, is confusing, when you're searching for how to add a calendar event on google and you get an answer that says "added event"

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** CalendarService which can create Event and Open Calendar.

```
import Foundation
import EventKit
import UIKit

final class CalendarService {

  class func openCalendar(with date: Date) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "calshow:\(date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)") else {
      return
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
  }

  class func addEventToCalendar(title: String,
                                description: String?,
                                startDate: Date,
                                endDate: Date,
                                completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { () -> Void in
      let eventStore = EKEventStore()

      eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
        if (granted) && (error == nil) {
          let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
          event.title = title
          event.startDate = startDate
          event.endDate = endDate
          event.notes = description
          event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
          do {
            try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
          } catch let e as NSError {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              completion?(false, e)
            }
            return
          }
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion?(true, nil)
          }
        } else {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion?(false, error as NSError?)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**Using**

```
CalendarService.addEventToCalendar(title: "TITLE",
                                               description: "DESCRIPTION",
                                               startDate: startDate,
                                               endDate: endDate,
                                               completion: { (success, error) in
                                                if success {
                                                    CalendarService.openCalendar(with: startDate)
                                                } else if let error = error {
                                                    print(error)
                                                }
    })
```